# ISolrQueryResults not working with solrNet 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, solrnet

ISolrQueryResults was working with solrNet 3.0

like my code with solrNet 3.0 was

```
       ISolrOperations<ProductTest2> solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<ProductTest2>>();
       ISolrQueryResults<ProductTest2> powerArticles  = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("is_OneCategoryActive:true") , new QueryOptions
        {
            FilterQueries = new[] { new SolrQueryByRange<Int32>("bestsellercurrent",1, 5) },
            Start = 0,
            Rows = 5
        }
         );
```

Now its stop working with solrNet 4.0. Please suggest me what i need to change.

Answer (score 7):

The `ISolrQueryResults` interface was removed with the SolrNet 0.4.0 Beta1 Release. You can just replace it with `SolrQueryResults`. Please see the Breaking Changes section of the [release notes](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/12/solrnet-040-beta-1-released.html).

So the following will now work:

```
 ISolrOperations<ProductTest2> solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<ProductTest2>>();
 SolrQueryResults<ProductTest2> powerArticles  = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("is_OneCategoryActive:true") , new QueryOptions
    {
        FilterQueries = new[] { new SolrQueryByRange<Int32>("bestsellercurrent",1, 5) },
        Start = 0,
        Rows = 5
    }
     );
```